# If $g$ is discontinuous and $fg$ is continuous then $f$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

> Prove or Provide Counterexample;
>   Suppose $f:(a,b)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is such that for all discontinuous functions $g:(a,b)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ the product $fg$ is continuous.Then $f$ is continuous.

How would I go about proving\disproving this, as I can't seem to find a counter example wherein both $f$ and $g$ are discontinuous and $fg$ are continuous. Or would this counter example work?
$$g(x) = \begin{cases} 0 &\mbox{if } x > 0 \\ 
1 & \mbox{if } x \leq 0. \end{cases}$$ and $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 &\mbox{if } x > 0 \\ 
0 & \mbox{if } x \leq 0. \end{cases}$$
Class as a counterxample??

Comment: @TZakrevskiy The questions reads “such that *for all* discontinuous functions $g$ …”.

Comment: @k.stm aaah, so in that case it must be true the only way $fg$ is continuous for all discontinuous $g$ implies $f$ must be continuous. But how would I prove this??

Comment: @Kimo yes, you're right, I didn't see that.

Answer (score 2):

Strong hint: By choosing a discontinuous function $g$ which is equal to $1$ at some point $c \in (a,b)$ and zero elsewhere, I can tell something about $f(c)$.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure what is meant by “discontinuous” here – it could be *discontinuous at some point* or *discontinuous at all points*. Usually people mean the former definition. But that would make the exercise way less interesting than what you had in mind.

For any point $x ∈ (a..b)$, construct a discontinuous function $g_x$ such that $fg_x = f$ in a neighbourhood of $x$. That should be straightforward. What can you conclude?